# JSON encoding in php

Tags: php, json

How to encode this json in php?
I don't want create any classes!

```
{
    "NAME": "name",
    "ADDR": {
        "PLACE": "place",
        "STATE": "state"
    },
    "MOB": "mobile"
}
```

Comment: encode or decode?, the string is already in json format

Comment: i want to create json like that in php??

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/json_encode) _first_. There are loads of examples on that page to show you how to generate JSON like that.

Answer (score 1):

create an array in php and use json_encode

```
$arr = array(
"NAME" => "name",
    "ADDR"=> array(
        "PLACE" => "place",
        "STATE" =>  "state"
    ),
    "MOB"=> "mobile"
);

$json = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: down vote without comment?

Comment: Don't expect comments on downvotes, just take it to mean someone felt that the answer was "not useful." (I'm not seeing why they would, other than that answering questions that are sure to be duplicates and/or closed for "no effort" *could* be seen as not useful. I wouldn't downvote this answer on that basis.)

Comment: you're most welcome. ;)

Comment: Please select the answer if it helped you. thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $temp_json = ' {
    "NAME": "name",
    "ADDR":
    {
        "PLACE": "place",
        "STATE": "state"
        },
        "MOB": "mobile"
    }';
// Decode above json to array object Format
print_r(json_decode($temp_json));

$temp_ary = array(
    "NAME" => "name",
    "ADDR" => array(
        "PLACE" => "place",
        "STATE" => "state"
    ),
    "MOB" => "mobile"
);
// Encode above array to Json Format
echo json_encode($temp_ary);
```

Comment: @a4arpan Well, this guy has also added code for decode.

Comment: @rayy the question was related to encode not decode

Comment: @a4arpan Extra information never hurts anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the JSON string by hand (be careful with encodings).

However it is idiomatic to convert a Php array into JSON with json_encode.

Here is an example of constructing a string (using heredoc) and sending it out with Php.  You could substitute variables if you want to keep it simple.

```
<?php
#get_json.php

$json =<<<JSON
{
    "NAME": "name",
    "ADDR": {
        "PLACE": "place",
        "STATE": "state"
    },
    "MOB": "mobile"
}
JSON;

// Send JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

Comment: $json = <<<JSON{}    how it works......I'm getting malformed JSON

Comment: the sample above works, I checked it using a JSON validator.

Comment: However it could fail if you had the wrong text encoding on the text file (should be utf-8).  You are better off using json_encode than constructing the string by hand where it is likely you could stumble with an encoding or escaping issue.

Comment: It is the most easy way .....creating JSON.....thanks i got it. I don't know how it works.......can you please send any reference to that method or please explain!..

Comment: It's just a string using heredoc syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc  , that is then printed out.  The header line hints to the requesting client that the pay load is JSON.

Answer (score -1):

From what i understand , you want  to prude a similiar json object by using PHP, right?

You can store the information in a PHP array and then just encode it to json using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
$x = array(
   "name"=>"JOHN",
   "addrs"=> array(
           "place"=>"string",
           "state"=> "something"
           )
);

echo json_encode($x);
```

Comment: copying my answer? lol

Comment: well... didnt copy but i assume everyone wrote the same.. no... :-)

Answer (score -1):

In PHP you can encode json using `json_encode`

```
$json = json_encode(array(
    "NAME" => "name",
    "ADDR" => array(
        "PLACE" => "place",
        "STATE" => "state"
    ),
    "MOB" => "mobile"
));
```

and decode it using `json_decode`;

```
$array = json_decode('{
    "NAME": "name",
    "ADDR": {
        "PLACE": "place",
        "STATE": "state"
    },
    "MOB": "mobile"
}', true);
```